# CodenameOne Android build fails

Tags: codenameone, build-error

Was working yesterday. Today got this error when send android build:
Server Detailed Error Message:

## Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error

Comment: What is your question here? Please, introduce the context of your problem. With your information, there is no way we can reproduce your problem. See "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This was a temporary error which was fixed in the build cloud servers